# FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION with single String value, RecycleView/Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm stuck with an issue, where i'm trying to create `RecyclerView` with data binded from `Firebase Firestore`, `Firestore CollectionReference` contains documents with single value `"name"`, but when i am binding it, it says `FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION` and saying;

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.example.ashaneen.firebaseapp, PID: 28014
>                                                                                     java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
>                                                                                         at android.graphics.Outline.setRoundRect(Outline.java:175)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.getOutline(GradientDrawable.java:1524)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable.getOutline(InsetDrawable.java:241)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.getOutline(RippleDrawable.java:680)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewOutlineProvider$1.getOutline(ViewOutlineProvider.java:38)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.rebuildOutline(View.java:12141)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.invalidateDrawable(View.java:16796)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.invalidateDrawable(TextView.java:5405)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:385)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.invalidateSelf(RippleDrawable.java:711)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.cancelExitingRipples(RippleDrawable.java:239)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.jumpToCurrentState(RippleDrawable.java:223)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(View.java:17168)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.widget.TextView.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(TextView.java:5339)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:6321)
>                                                                                                                                                                             at  01-08 16:25:39.472 28014-28014/com.example.ashaneen.firebaseapp
>   E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size =
>   19834640)

FriendsFragment.class

```
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = "FriendsFragment";

    public FriendsFragment() {
    }

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    CollectionReference friends = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").document(user.getUid()).collection("friends");

    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends,container);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: "+ friends);
        final Query query = friends.limit(2);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.id_recycleViewFriends);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<FriendModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<FriendModel>()
                .setQuery(query,FriendModel.class)
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .build();

        FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<FriendModel,FriendHolder> adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<FriendModel, FriendHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(FriendHolder holder, int position, FriendModel model) {
                   holder.setName(model.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public FriendHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new FriendHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.single_friend_row_test,parent,false));
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

FriendModel.class

```
public class FriendModel
     {
        private String name;


        public FriendModel() {
        }


        public FriendModel(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }
```

FriendHolder.class

```
public class FriendHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView name;

    public FriendHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_name);
    }

    public void setName(String sName) {
      name.setText(sName);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution, the problem was with

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
```

there should be `getActivity()` as parameter instead of `getApplicationContext()`
although problem is solved I would highly appreciated if someone knows why this works this way.